# How to create a domain class automatically in Groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

Anyone knows how to create a **domain class automatically** in groovy?

Here is my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn"
 // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        grailsCentral()
        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        mavenCentral()
        //mavenLocal()
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    ebr()
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
grails.project.dependency.resolution = { plugins{compile ":svn:1.0.2" } }
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.5'
    }

    plugins {
        build(":tomcat:$grailsVersion",
              ":release:1.0.0") {
            export = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean automatically create a groovy domain starting from the database table you can try with the [db reverse plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/db-reverse-engineer)

Comment: Following error occured when am trying to install **db reverse plugin**

Comment: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: org.grails.plugins#svn;1.0.0.M1: not found
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins#svn;1.0.0.M1: not found

Comment: Add this dependencies in your BuildConfig.groovy grails.project.dependency.resolution = { plugins{ compile ":svn:1.0.2" } }

Comment: Again the same error...dependencies {       
grails.project.dependency.resolution = { plugins{compile ":svn:1.0.2" } }  }
any mistake in this dependency code???

Comment: try run "grails refresh-dependencies" and then "grails dependency-report" and see in the report if svb 1.0.0.M1 is still pulled in and by who